# Could attempting to reset my BIOS partially fail and brick my laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios, uefi, firmware, reset

I'm looking of a method to reset or bypass the UEFI/BIOS admin password on my laptop, but I'm concerned I might brick my device.  Does anyone have any knowledge about this?

**Device:**

- Model Name: ASUS TUF A15 (2020)
- Model Number: FAV506IV
- BIOS mode: UEFI
- ASUS BIOS version: 316 (FAV506IV.316) (20210311) (Not sure what the full AMI # is)
- BIOS Vendor: AMI BIOS
- OS: Windows 10 Home (Up to date)
- Secure Boot State: enabled
- TPM version: 2.0

**More specially, I am considering:**

- using ASUS WinFlah to attempt to re-flash my BIOS (EZ Flash doesn't do anything)
- Opening the laptop and disconnecting the battery (I don't think it has a CMOS coin cell / reset jumpers)

My question is - could any of these actions partially reset the BIOS, making it unable to boot but still retain the password?  I read that BIOS passwords are sometimes stored on persistent storage.

Comment: I cannot say for your machine, but whenever I have done a BIOS (UEFI) update, started the update and not lost power (i take steps to ensure this), I have not bricked the mahcine

Comment: For anyone wondering about the underlying issue, I tried to set the BIOS password to Q@x97Zl:r8YK6^c{ and it was accepted, but the login prompt won't take special characters.  I wrote separate [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/qo7608/locked_out_of_admin_access_asus_tuf_bios/) about that on r/techsupport .